# Threading queue in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

Currently working on a project, im struggeling with threading and queue at the moment, the issue is that all threads take the same item in the queue.

Reproduceable example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void Test(queue<string> queue){
    
    while (!queue.empty()) {
    
        string proxy = queue.front();
        cout << proxy << "\n";
        
        queue.pop();
    
    }
    
}

int main()
{
    
    queue<string> queue;
    
    queue.push("101.132.186.39:9090");
    queue.push("95.85.24.83:8118");
    queue.push("185.211.193.162:8080");
    queue.push("87.106.37.89:8888");
    queue.push("159.203.61.169:8080");
    
    std::vector<std::thread> ThreadVector;
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        ThreadVector.emplace_back([&]() {Test(queue); });
    }
    
    for (auto& t : ThreadVector){
        t.join();
    }

    ThreadVector.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use mutex: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard

Comment: @Asesh That's not enough. OP is passing a _copy_ of the queue to every thread, so each thread will have the same data to crunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving each thread its own copy of the queue. I imagine that what you want is all the threads to work on the same queue and for that you will need to use some synchronization mechanism when multiple threads work on the **shared** queue as std queue is not thread safe.

edit: minor note: in your code you are spawning 11 threads not 10.

edit 2: OK, try this one to begin with:

```
std::mutex lock_work;
std::mutex lock_io;

void Test(queue<string>& queue){

while (!queue.empty()) {
    string proxy;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(lock_work);
        proxy = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
    }
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(lock_io);
        cout << proxy << "\n";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, I look what I can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this snippet:

```
void Test(std::queue<std::string> queue) { /* ... */ }
```

Here you pass a *copy* of the queue object to the thread.

This copy is local to each thread, so it gets destroyed after every thread exits so in the end your program does not have any effect on the actual `queue` object that resides in the `main()` function.

To fix this, you need to either make the parameter take a reference or a pointer:

```cpp
void Test(std::queue<std::string>& queue) { /* ... */ }
```

This makes the parameter directly refer to the `queue` object present inside `main()` instead of creating a copy.

Now, the above code is still not correct since `queue` is prone to [data-race](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-0619/geojs/index.html) and neither `std::queue` nor `std::cout` is thread-safe and can get interrupted by another thread while currently being accessed by one. To prevent this, use a [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex):

```cpp
// ...
#include <mutex>

// ...

// The mutex protects the 'queue' object from being subjected to data-race amongst different threads
// Additionally 'io_mut' is used to protect the streaming operations done with 'std::cout'
std::mutex mut, io_mut;

void Test(std::queue<std::string>& queue) {
    std::queue<std::string> tmp;
    {
        // Swap the actual object with a local temporary object while being protected by the mutex
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        std::swap(tmp, queue);
    }
    while (!tmp.empty()) {
        std::string proxy = tmp.front();
        {
            // Call to 'std::cout' needs to be synchronized
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(io_mut);
            std::cout << proxy << "\n";
        }
        tmp.pop();
    }
}
```

This synchronizes each thread call and prevents access from any other threads while `queue` is still being accessed by a thread.

**Edit:**

Alternatively, it'd be much faster in my opinion to make each thread wait until one of them receives a notification of your push to `std::queue`. You can do this through the use of [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable):

```cpp
// ...

#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

// ...

std::mutex mut1, mut2;
std::condition_variable cond;

void Test(std::queue<std::string>& queue, std::chrono::milliseconds timeout = std::chrono::milliseconds{10}) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut1);
    // Wait until 'queue' is not empty...
    cond.wait(lock, [queue] { return queue.empty(); });
    while (!queue.empty()) {
        std::string proxy = std::move(queue.front());
        std::cout << proxy << "\n";
        queue.pop();
    }
}

// ...

int main() {
    std::queue<string> queue;
    
    std::vector<std::thread> ThreadVector;
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        ThreadVector.emplace_back([&]() { Test(queue); });
    
    // Notify the vectors of each 'push()' call to 'queue'
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut2);
        queue.push("101.132.186.39:9090");
        cond.notify_one();
    }
    
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut2);
        queue.push("95.85.24.83:8118");
        cond.notify_one();
    }
    
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut2);
        queue.push("185.211.193.162:8080");
        cond.notify_one();
    }
    
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut2);
        queue.push("87.106.37.89:8888");
        cond.notify_one();
    }
    
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut2);
        queue.push("159.203.61.169:8080");
        cond.notify_one();
    }

    for (auto& t : ThreadVector)
        t.join();

    ThreadVector.clear();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really work, it's working like if it was running only on one thread. My goal is to multithread a function run it X times simultaneously

Comment: @VRX You *could* try to swap the referenced queue object with an empty temporary and then do things on the temporary which you could then swap back with the actual object. I have included that in the answer, but I doubt if that will make it much faster.

Comment: Im getting "deque empty before pop" also it still works like on one thread.

Comment: Im doing requests with the cpr library maybe it's because of that?

Comment: Why are you creating a local tmp copy of the queue? You are correctly serializing modifications to the queue but there is actually a data race: a thread can discard any changes made to the queue by an other thread.

Comment: it is a good point that cout also needs to be serialized. I will be pedantic and add that I would use a different mutex so that IO doesn't interfere  with work on the queue

Comment: In your second version the test function doesn't loop over the queue elements so each thread checks once if there are data to pop and returns.

Comment: You keep changing your answers and obsoleting my comments :) You added a loop inside the mutex protected region which actually makes ALL queue processing single threaded :)